# Пропадает бэкграунд

Tags: html, css

Почему не отображается бекграунд при таком коде?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
#home {
  background-image: url("../images/cover-bg.jpg");
  background-color: #222;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 0;
}
.intro {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<section id="home" class="text-center">
  <div class="home-overlay"></div>
  <div class="intro horizontal-center">
    <p class="homeIntro">Lorem lorem Lorem lorem</p>
    <h1>Lorem lorem </h1>
    <p class="homeIntro">Lorem lorem Lorem loremLorem lorem
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Ссылка правильная?

Comment: Да, ссылка правильная. Просто для наглядности, что бекграунд не отображается по какой-то причине(Очевидно, position: absolute), а как это исправить - я не знаю :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите ширину и высоту для `#home`. Когда у дочернего элемента стоит `position: absolute`, то родитель структурно его не видит и по-этому не учитывает его размеры; и из за этого ширина и высота `#home` = 0.

```css
#home {
  background-image: url("../images/cover-bg.jpg");
  background-color: #222;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 0;

  /* Ширина и высота */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.intro {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<section id="home" class="text-center">
  <div class="home-overlay"></div>
  <div class="intro horizontal-center">
    <p class="homeIntro">Lorem lorem Lorem lorem</p>
    <h1>Lorem lorem </h1>
    <p class="homeIntro">Lorem lorem Lorem loremLorem lorem
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что блок `#home` не имеет высоту, из-за того что внутри него абсолютно спозиционированный блок, который не находится в потоке документа.

```css
#home {
  height: 1000px;
  background: #222 url("https://mobidevices.ru/images/2017/01/MacBook-Pro-2016.jpg") no-repeat 50% / cover fixed;
  padding: 0;
}
.intro {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<section id="home" class="text-center">
  <div class="home-overlay"></div>
  <div class="intro horizontal-center">
    <p class="homeIntro">Lorem lorem Lorem lorem</p>
    <h1>Lorem lorem </h1>
    <p class="homeIntro">Lorem lorem Lorem loremLorem lorem
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Как не хорошо воровать ответы... ай-ай-ай. Сначала прочли в комментариях, что я предположил, что это из за ссылки и добавили ответ, а потом скопировали мой ответ про размеры..

Comment: Юрий, одновременно опубликовали. Ваш комментарий до сих пор не читал и не знаю что там. Просто открыл IDE и искал там ответ. А когда опубликовал - увидел там.

Comment: @Yuri в комментах вижу только "Ссылка правильная?". Так что не знаю, что я мог из него подсмотреть. Да и ответ примитивный же.

Comment: Ну - ну..... :)